# If $\sum_{n>0}^\infty c_{n}z^{n}$ has a radius of convergence R then the series $\sum_{n>0}^\infty \frac {c_n}{n!} $ has a radius of convergence +∞.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose the series $\sum_{n>0}^\infty c_{n}z^{n}$ has a radius of convergence $R \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ Justify that the series $\sum_{n>0}^\infty \frac {c_n}{n!} $ has a radius of convergence +∞.

I need to use this fact for a theorem that I am proving but could not prove it

Comment: Use the ratio test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to see why this holds. Let us just work with the fundamentals. Think for a moment what is it that you are trying to show? You want to show that no matter what $X\in \mathbb{C},$ You choose the series $\sum\limits_{n}c_n\frac{|x|^n}{n!}<\infty.$

Given all that we know, let us just try to bound this series (Hoping that we would succeed). The first thing to note is that if I fix $r<R,$ then $\sum c_nr^n<\infty$ (Why?). Using this, let us re-write our series as follows.
\begin{align*}
\sum_n c_n\frac{|x|^n}{n!}&=\sum_n (c_nr^n)\frac{(|x|/r)^n}{n!}.
\end{align*}

Take a pause at this moment and stare at the last expression for a minute or two. It will dawn at you that for sufficiently large $n,$ we have $\frac{(x/r)^n}{n!}<1.$ 
As a consequence, you can now see that except may be finitely many terms, we have $c_n\frac{|x|^n}{n!}\le c_nr^n.$ Since, we already know that $\sum_nc_nr^n<\infty,$ It follows that $$\sum_n c_n\frac{|x|^n}{n!}\le \infty.$$

There are of course slicker way to see why this is true, but I prefer doing things with first principle whenever possible because it is more revealing. And, after a while you don’t need to worry about these kind of issues, because you will see it.